# Which pattern/architecture follow to build Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, design-patterns, mobile, architecture

I started build an e-commerce app that allows people buy one item by turn. However, I don't have deep knowledge about Flutter app architecture to follow. The app will get all data from a server and will persist only basic user data in the mobile device. I want to know which are the patterns and architectures (state-management) to study and apply considering that I am a beginner in Flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your question is pretty subjective as it could have as many answers as State management libraries+architectures exist in flutter.
But I would step up and recommend something like shown [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6373413-state-management-with-provider).

The architecture uses Provider + ChangeNotifier which is recommended by google, and to me personally is both a simple and powerful approach.
You might be advised to use [Bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/) , which is indeed good too and also recommended by google [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) but in my opinion more complex for beginners. And there is nothing you can you do with Bloc that you can't achieve with provider.

Comment: Thank you! Was exactly this I was looking for. I saw this architecture in the flutter documentation, but the explanation was too much concise.

Comment: This question is related to this stack : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72462059/19101705